# avd disk is showing full storage

Tags: android, android-emulator

My code is showing running out of memory type of error.

I have wiped out data from avd but still it is showing same type of error.

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough disk space to run AVD 'Nexus_6_API_28'. Exiting...
```

this type of error it is showing

so please help me to solve this error so my app would run.

Comment: edit the emulator disk space by going to avd->select device->advanced->set size. This will wipe old data.

Comment: or, just delete that emulator and make a new one :)

Comment: i have done both but still it doesn't work.